# socket.fromfd for Windows

Tags: python, sockets, winapi, porting, file-descriptor

I am porting a Python-based web server from Linux to Windows. There is a call to socket.fromfd, which is only available in Unix and I've been trying to find a Windows-equivalent with no luck.

I came upon WinSock and WSADuplicateSocket, but these don't seem to be available in Python based on this post: [Can I use the winsock api from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551682/can-i-use-the-winsock-api-from-python)

I know there is also DuplicateHandle, but it is not reliable for sockets. Is there any reliable way to reproduce socket.fromfd for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a patch for this issue, for python windows. I haven`t tried it personally, but this link might help :
http://bugs.python.org/issue1378

Comment: nice find!  It appears the patch was checked in for Python 3, but never made it into the Python 2 line.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Python 2.7 though... But I will try to use the same idea as in the patch. I'll accept if I'll get it to work!