# Run a Scrapy spider in a Celery task on Windows

Tags: python, scrapy, celery

I'm trying to get a Scrapy spider to run in a Celery task on Windows under Python 2.7.

I have seen [Run a Scrapy spider in a Celery Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116493/run-a-scrapy-spider-in-a-celery-task) which is the latest question on how to get this working generally.

The issue I have is that the answer involves the use of the `billiard` package to get everything working.

Under the hood somewhere, `billiard` is making a call to the `socket.fromfd(fd, family, type[, proto])` method, which is not supported on Windows ([socket.fromfd for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627251/socket-fromfd-for-windows)) so it all falls apart.

Has anyone had any luck getting this (or a similar `twisted reactor` process) working on Windows?